# Is the assumption of constant variance violated in the following?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, residuals, heteroscedasticity, qq-plot

Is the assumption of constant variance violated in the following?

I am measuring point in a 3D coordinate system (X,Y,Z) using 10 different methods. One method is the golden standard (reference). The measurements are done at the same time for 40 different subjects repeated 2-3 times per subject. I end up with 105 measurements for each of the 10 methods. I am then interested in the length of the error compared to the reference (|Xerror| = |Xref-Xmethod|) in the X, Y and Z direction and the total error as the Euclidian distance (=sqrt(X^2+Y^2+Z^2)).

I want to see which method gives the smallest error in each of the directions (X,Y,Z) and also the lowest Eucledian distance. I have been using linear regression for this. With a model in for example the X direction as: |X| ~ 1+ method, where method is a categorical variable representing the 9 different methods tested (not including the reference). I have 9 x 105 = 945 observations.

Some different diagnostic plots can be seen below. I have used square-root transformation of the data to get a decent QQ-plot. My biggest concern is on the assumption of constant variance? But is there anything else which should concern me?

Additional info: the measurements are discrete (can only be integer numbers).

[image]

Comment: Are the estimates also restricted to be integers?  Note that even if X, Y and Z are integers usually the Euclidean distance will not be.

Comment: Thank you for interrest. The coefficients in the model are not restricted to be integers. The observations are integers. The eucledian distance is continues.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the lower plot in the left column, titled *Plot of residuals vs. fitted values*. Does it show some tendency for the residuals do be more spread out with increasing fitted values? I do not think so, so no indication of non-constant variance.

The qq-plot is close to linear, except the steep gradient at the lower left (corresponding to a hump in the corresponding histogram.) That indicates some lower bound on the residuals, which is maybe natural, since there is a lower bound (zero) on the observations, distances.  The leverages seems close to constant, which is good.  So nothing in particular to worry about.